# excel: compact version of a structured reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel table, I can refer to a "first_column" through the structured reference:

```
=Table1[[#This row];[first_column]]
```

In a complex formula it may be hard to read.

I noticed that:

```
=[first_column]
```

also works!

Before spreading the word, I would like to check it out on the docs, and... I didn't find anything.

Before starting using this feature massively, I need to be sure that's it's a reliable one. Can you provide links to documentation or other authoritative information?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=Table1[[#This row];[first_column]]` and `=[first_column]` are not the same. The first one refers to **one** cell. In your example the cell in [first_column] of the same row. The second one refers to the whole column data of the column [first_column]. In your example 3 cells {11;22;33}.

You will see this if you are using `=SUM(Table1[[#This row];[first_column]])` versus `=SUM([first_column])`.

There `=SUM([first_column])` is the same as `=SUM({11;22;33})`. But  `=[first_column]` in **one** cell would be the same as `={11;22;33}` in that one cell. And this only shows the first of the three values if applied in one cell only or the respective value of the row if applied to a range of three cells one below the other.

See: [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

The really shortcut for `=Table1[[#This row];[first_column]]` would be `=Table1[@[first_column]]` or `[@[first_column]]` if used in the same table. But this is not possible in Excel 2007.

All formulas are using semicolon as the list delimiter. Default would be comma for en_US Excel. But since it had be used in the question also, I have take it.

Comment: Ok, i tried SUM([first_column]) and it gives the same result for all rows. But how is it possible that it works then? I've tried defining a regular interval, say from A1:A5, i've filled with numbers from 1 to 5 and i gave it a name: "wow". =sum(wow) gives 15 but =wow gives always 1. There is something going on here, something table-specific.

Comment: Nothing table-specific but something array-specific. See my supplement.

Comment: sorry, what i don't understand is how is it possible that ={11;22;33} shows the second value in the second row. It should show always the first one.

Comment: No, if an array `={11;22;33}` is applied to three cells one below the other, then each of the three cells shows the respective value of the row.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I can't reproduce such a feature in a regular (non table) sheet.

Comment: In A1 put 11, in A2 put 22, in A3 put 33. Now in B1 put the formula `=$A$1:$A$3` and fill down that formula. In B1 it shows 11, in B2 it shows 22, in B3 it shows 33, nevertheless it is always the same `=$A$1:$A$3`. In B4 it shows `#VALUE!` because there is not more a respective value for the 4th row.